# Can't configure Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

I've installed PHP 5.3.8 on my localhost and I tried to configure Xdebug, but for some reason, Xdebug doesn't seem to work. I've added following lines to my `php.ini` file:

```
zend_extension = C:\Server\PHP\5.3.8\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.3-5.3-vc9.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=”dbgp”
```

And of course, the file in the `zend_extension` path is exists. And I also have tried restarting my Apache.
Is there a specific type of Xdebug for every version of PHP or is this just a matter of a bad configuration?

**EDIT:**
I've tried every 2.1.3 and 2.1.2 dll available on the Xdebug site, but none of them seems to work...

**EDIT 2:**
Ok, great, I just got the latest Xdebug version working, but my `var_dump`'s still look awful... Here is what they look like:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "text" [1]=> string(4) "node" [2]=> string(6) "blabla" }
```

But they used to look like this:

```
array(3) 
    0 => 'text' string(4) 
    1 => 'node' string(4)
    2 => 'blabla' string(6)
```

How do I get them to look like this?

Comment: check PHP from command line write down here what error are you getting.

Comment: I hope you don't really mean PHP **3.5.5**.

Comment: Holy crap... nope. My mistake. I meant 5.3.5

Comment: does zend_extension need ".dll" tacked on the end?

Comment: Yep, it does, but didn't made a difference

Comment: The var_dumps require `html_errors` set to 1 in `php.ini`

Comment: How do they look in source? You might need to <pre> around the var_dump output to see them formatted like that in the browser.

Comment: display_errors = On

html_errors = On

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xdebug has a fantastic phpinfo() output parser which determines exactly what version of Xdebug you need and even gives you personalised instructions based on this. Simply visit:

http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php

and you'll be up and running in no time.

Comment: The setup is suggesting I have to install `php_xdebug-2.1.3-5.3-vc6.dll` but the given link is broken...

Comment: Oh you mean the Xdebug dll it says you need isn't available from them. Perhaps you can try googling the specific one you need. Failing that, perhaps you should explain what you mean by 'doesn't seem to work'.

Comment: Apparently this version isn't supported, you need a newer version of XAMPP: http://xdebug.org/archives/xdebug-general/2166.html

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments. I've updated my PHP version to 5.3.8 and this time, the suggested dll on the `find-binary.php` link was found. I installed it, but `phpinfo()` still isn't showing me the Xdebug path...

Comment: Paste your new phpinfo into their parser again and see if it says it's succesfully installed. Did you restart your web server yet?

Comment: Ok, great. Xdebug is installed... But my var_dumps still look awful... How can I get them to order properly? See my second edit in my question.

Comment: VC6 builds are no longer supported from Xdebug 2.1.2 upwards. Exactly what deed02392 said 52 mins ago. —Derick

Answer (score 2):

If your var_dump looks "awful" then you need to set html_errors=1. Xdebug respects PHP's normal error reporting settings and (sadly) in PHP 5.3 that default now has html_errors=0. Simply set it back to 1 in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the xdebug version must be compatible with the php version. Yours look well (you can check it in the download page: [enter link description here](http://xdebug.org/download.php)).

Next, check the Zend Engine is running with xdebug. phpinfo() must return something like:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans
```

If you don't see the line "with Xdebug..." the problem is on the dll. If you see that line, xdebug is running ok. Then the problem comes from the client side, maybe due to a configuration problem.

Comment: There is no "with Xdebug" line in my phpinfo. So I'm guessing the problem is with the dll? How can I find the correct dll? The link on the Xdebug (http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php) shows me a file that doens't exists anymore...